# Como puedo integrar datso de sql server a dynamics 365? bi-direccional

Tags: sql-server, microsoft, dynamics-crm

mi problema es el siguiente.

He creado una tabla en sql server y cree un flow que agrega lineas desde dynamics 365 a sql server (Me la agrega bien)
[image: Imagen del flow que me integra los datos a una tabla en sql]

Pero el problema esta en cuando creo otro flow para que cuando se modifiquen los datos en sql server, se modifique el registro creado en dynamics 365
[image: Flow que me modifica los datos en sql y actualiza en dynamics (no funcional)]

No se si este es el mejor metodo para hacerlo o si el flow que hice esta mal. necesito que me guíen o me ayuden en este caso.

estoy conectando los datos de sql en el flow con un gateway

espero sus respuestas y de antemano, muchas gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido(a) a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender sobre el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. Te invito también a leer [ask]. La pregunta actual carece de una serie de detalles como para ser respondida y me temo que la comunidad terminará cerrándola, por lo mismo. Te invito a editarla y agregar una explicación más completa de lo que estás intentando hacer y cuál es la dificultad que tienes, idealmente un [mcve]. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Para poder actualizar los datos en Dynamics 365 tenés que conocer el GUID del registro ¿le estás enviado ese dato correctamente?
Si no tenés el GUID, podés hacer una búsqueda por otro parámetro con la acción "Obtener registros", ahí usás el filtro oData para buscar los registros. Esta acción te devuelve un vector, por lo que es necesario que primero lo proceses para obtener finalmente el GUID, con ese dato vas a poder actualizar el registro en Dynamics 365.
Siempre fijate que los tipos de datos coincidan para que no te de error.
Espero te sirva.
Saludos.